# deepcopy/clone derived class to base class

Tags: java, serialization, clone

How can I clone (copy base class part) a derived class to base class.

In my case base class is a JPA entity and derived class have some stuff for swing/ui.
I thought clone via gson/json serialization should work,but have different issue with that.

```
Base d=new Derived();
Base b=(Base) SerializationUtils.clone(d);
System.out.println(b.getClass().getSimpleName());   //-->Derived
   //hibernateSession.save(b) -> refers to derived class
```

Is there any simple way other than manually copying all properties from derived to base?

Comment: No amount of upcasting is going to help you, this is purely compiler stuff. Plus, it's an ill-defined problem in general, which means that you probably won't find an out-of-the box solution. Would it be too much pain to do it manually?

Comment: Why do you need to do this given your `Dervided` is a `Base` class? What are you trying to achieve that a cast or deep copy won't do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all levels of the inheritance tree support the Java Beans API. Now you can write a certain-level cloner like this:

```
public <T> T specialClone( T obj, Class<T> type ) {
    T result = type.newInstance();
    Class<?> current = type;
    while( current != null ) {
        BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo( current );
        for( PropertyDescriptor pd: info.getPropertyDescriptors() ) {
            Object value = pd.getReadMethod().invoke( obj );
            pd.getWriteMethod().invoke( result, value );
        }
        current = current.getSuperClass();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that you might want to cache the read/write methods because the method calls are synchronized.

When I do stuff like this, I usually examine the beans once and create helper objects that wrap the two methods so I can work like this:

```
for( Helper h : get( current ) ) {
    h.copy( obj, result );
}

public Helper[] get( Class<?> type ) {
    ... look in cache. If nothing there, create helper using  PropertyDescriptors.
}
```